# QIWI API: Выставить счет на Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, qiwi

Прошу помочь разобраться с следующей проблемой:
Я хочу создать счет при помощи API на GAS (Google App Script), но постоянно ловлю "http.message.conversion.failed". Мб я что-то в этой жизни делаю не так?

```
function myFunction() {
  url = "https://api.qiwi.com/partner/bill/v1/bills/" + "aaabbbccc";

  var options = {
    "method": "put",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + secret_key,
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "accept": "application/json"
    },
    "payload": {
      'amount': {
        'currency': 'RUB',
        'value': '1.00'
      },
      'expirationDateTime': '2022-07-20T00:16:50.632+03:00'
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка пропала при замене options:

```
var options = {
"method": "put",
"headers": {
  "Authorization": "Bearer " + secret_key,
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "accept": "application/json"
},
"payload": JSON.stringify({
  amount: {
    currency: 'RUB',
    value: '1.00'
  },
  expirationDateTime: '2022-07-20T00:16:50.632+03:00'
}),
"muteHttpExceptions": true
};
```